# Reference value used in Firebase Firestore document gets prefixed with project ID in Firebase Storage security rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, firebase-security

Consider the following Firebase Storage security rules:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
    function postRef(postId) {
        return /databases/(default)/documents/posts/$(postId);
    }

    match /b/{bucket}/o {
        match /posts/{postId}/images/{imageId} {
            allow create: if request.auth != null
                && firestore.get(firestore.get(postRef(postId)).data.topic).data.something;
        }
    }
}
```

Field `topic` of the `post` document contains a value of reference data type in the format `topic/{topicId}`.

The problem I am facing is that the function `firestore.get` accepts path in the format `/databases/(default)/documents/posts/{postId}`, however, the reference in the `topic` field of the `post` document returned from the function `firestore.get` contains path in format `/projects/my-project/databases/(default)/documents/topic/{topicId}` – note it is prefixed by a project id.

This leads to an error because the `firestore.get` function expects path without the leading project id (`/databases/(default)/documents/topic/{topicId}`).

Interestingly enough, the same rule used in Firebase Firestore security rules works fine, there is no problem with the reference value being prefixed by the project upon fetching.

My question is, is there some way, using Firebase Storage security rules, to make this work? I have an alternative solution involving the removal of reference data types from the Firestore and replacing them with a string value of the document ID. However, I would like to avoid this solution because it would introduce unnecessary refactoring of the codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there's no alternative solution from Firebase Documentation itself.  You may have to stick to your workarounds for now with this issue. [Cross-service Security](https://firebase.blog/posts/2022/09/announcing-cross-service-security-rules) Rules are still new to Firebase. All the available functionalities are stated in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/rules-conditions#enhance_with_firestore).

You may want to file a [Feature Request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features) for this case.